# How do I pass the data to the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

When I select a product, the other `AutoComplete` for `colors` should filter based on the available variations of colors where the quantity is not equal to 0. For example, if I'll select the product `Tumbler`, the colors should be Black, pink, and green. And if I'll select the product `Notebook`, the color should be Green, Red, and Black.

1. The list of the products shows in the `AutoComplete` as options **(working)**
2. According to the what product was selected, it shows the available colors whose quantity is not equal to `0` for that selected product. For example, I chose Tumbler, this will show the list of colors the tumbler has which are Black, Pink, and Green. And if I’ll choose the product Shirt, the list of colors that will display are Blue and Black. **(Not working)**
3. Pass the data that contains the available colors of the selected product to the `NestedArray` component and show up as `options` of the `AutoComplete`. **(Not working)**

How can I do this? Thank you.

I have recreated the problem in codesandbox:

**FieldArray Component**

```
const FieldArray = ({  products }) => {

  const options = products.map(
    (object) =>
      object.prodName +
      " - " +
      object.size +
     
  );

  console.log(fields, "f");

  const selectedProduct = fields.map((object) => object.product);
  console.log(selectedProduct, "selectedProduct");

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={item.id} style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
              <Controller
                control={control}
                name={`order.${index}.product`}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value = "", ...rest } }) => (
                  <Autocomplete
                    {...rest}
                    onInputChange={(e, newValue) => {
                      onChange(newValue);
                    }}
                    inputValue={value}
                    options={options}
                    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                      option?.value === value?.value
                    }
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                        label="Product"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <NestedArray
                nestIndex={index}
                {...{ control, register, products }}
              />   //pass the corresponding colors here of the selected product (AutoComplete) in the above component
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <section>
       //button to add more product
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FieldArray;
```

**NestedArray Component:**

To show the corresponding `colors` here according to what Product (AutoComplete) was selected in the above component

```
const NestedArray = ({ nestIndex, control, register, products }) => {
  const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: `order[${nestIndex}].variation`,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {fields.map((item, k) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.id} style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
            <label>{k + 1}</label>
             //the quantity input here
             <Controller
            control={control}
            name={`order[${nestIndex}].variation[${k}].color`}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value = "", ...rest } }) => (
              <Autocomplete
                {...rest}
                onInputChange={(e, newValue) => {
                  onChange(newValue);
                }}
                inputValue={value}
                options={options}
                isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                  option?.value === value?.value
                }
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Color"
                    variant="outlined"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                )}
              />
            )}
          />
   
    </div>
  );
};

export default NestedArray;
```

Comment: Hi pennie, is very hard to read all this code without implementation, I advice you to create a live demo in codepen or  https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @Thescion ohh alright, updated the post with the codesandbox

Comment: Great, but stil I can't understand exactlly what is wrong here. You tring to select color and pass it to the nestededArry component?

Comment: @Thescion For example, the user chose the product "Tumbler". In the `products`, "Tumbler" have these following colors; Blank, Pink, and Green. I wanted these colors to be passed as `options` in the `NestedArray` component

Answer (score 2):

I did not dig in to see how `react-hook-form` works, so you can probably come up with a nicer solution.

Here is my solution in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-from-reddit-with-data-setting-up-a-setproduct-forked-wyo8i2?file=/src/index.js

To describe the changes I made:

- I added a state variable in `FieldArray` to hold the currently selected product. (you probably incorporate this better using your form library). The value is then passed to `NestedArray`.
- Edited the rendered `<Autocomplete>` props in `FieldArray` to include `onChange` instead of `onInputChange` (used onChange instead of onInputChange to get the product object instead of the generated label as an argument to the function).

I aslo had to map the colors of the product object to an array similar to the one you had created.

```
const options = Object.keys(product.colorMap).map((color) => ({
      label: color,
      value: color
  }))
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. There's just some kind of a problem, if I'll click a product and then click the `x` button of the `AutoComplete`, it does have this error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'prodName')`

Comment: @PennieCorhon the argument `product` of the function in the `onChange` prop is null when you remove the product selection, hence the error. I did a quick fix in the codesandbox link in my answer, but I would encourage you to try to fix it on your own first.

Comment: @PennieCorhon I also noticed that you cannot type a product in the input box to bring up matching options anymore. It probably broke when I switched the `onInputChange` prop to `onChange`. You should filter the available options based on the value of the input. I do not want to solve this for you, but I would look at the [Autocomplete - API](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/) to understand the provided props. [Autocomplete - Component](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/) might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Pennie, for building a dynamic options (if I understood what you are tring to develop here).

I think you should pass the options as props into the
nestedFieldsArray.js,

fieldsArray.js->

```
<NestedArraynestIndex={index}
                {...{ control, register, options }}
              />
```

and in the nestedFieldsArray.js->

```
const NestedArray = ({ nestIndex, control, register, options }) => {
  const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: `order[${nestIndex}].variation`
  });
```

and remove the hard coded options-

```
 const options = [ //should be delete 
    { label: "red", value: "red" },
    { label: "green", value: "green" },
    { label: "blue", value: "blue" }
  ];
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-from-reddit-with-data-forked-ledb12?file=/src/nestedFieldArray.js

Comment: but the codesandbox shows the list of the products. I kind of wanted to display the colors according to what was chosen as the product in AutoComplete. For exampe, I chose Tumbler, this will show the list of `colors` the tumbler has which are Black, Pink, and Green. If I'll choose the product Shirt, the list of `colors` that will display are Blue and Black